# mongoose relation between models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I have two models: Item and Hashtag.
Hashtag model should contain only name and Item model should contain a list of hashtags (represented by ids).
This is what I've done:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    hashtags: [ { type: Schema.ObjectId, 'default': null, ref: 'Hashtag' } ],
}); 

var HashtagSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, 'default': '', trim: true },
    items: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Page' }]
});
```

This is how I try to create an Item:

```
   var item = new Item({
        hashtags: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    });
    item.save(function (err, item) {
        if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
        res.json(item);
    });
```

Unfortunately I get this error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "a,b,c" at path "hashtags"
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using [references](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) instead of [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html), you need to create the hashtag objects first:

```
var tagnames = ['a','b','c'];
var hashtags = {}; //for referencing quickly by name later
for (var h in tagnames){
    var tag = new Hashtag({
        name: tagnames[h]
    });
    tag.save(function (err, item) {
        if (err) console.log('error:',err);
        hashtags[item.name] = item; 
    });
}
```

Once you have the hashtags created, you can reference them::

```
var item = new Item({
    hashtags: [hashtags.a._id,hashtags.b._id,hashtags.c._id]
});
item.save(function (err, item) {
    if (err) return res.json({ error: err });
    res.json(item);
});
```

Then you can use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to automatically turn the object ids into documents:

```
Item.find({})
    .populate('hashtags')
    .exec(function (err, items) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        //items are populated with hashtags
    });
```

If you are just doing simple tagging, then [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) may be a better fit.  They allow you to declare and save child documents all in one step.  The trade-off is that subdocuments belong exclusively to their parent documents. They are not references so any aggregations on them must be done manually.

Comment: Is there any way to bind the hashtags inserts somehow to the model? Some kind of constraint?

Comment: Yes, you can use [subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) if hashtags can belong solely to one Item.

Comment: Later I want to be able to show all the hashtags. Is there any way to add something like "before create" that creates hashtags if needed and convert names to ids?

Comment: Yes, look at the [middleware hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html). Please mark as accepted if I answered your question.